# Highcharts - How to specify dimensions of rectangles

Tags: angularjs, highcharts

I working with highcharts in angularjs and I want to change the background like in the picture. Also, I want to be able to specify dimentions of rectangles
[image]

**UPDATE**
The problem is when I give the parameters to draw my rectangles, it's affecting all the div and what I want is to draw the rectangles on my chart surface only. The problem is because of "this" which I'm using in my code and I want now to replace it with chart. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `renderer` to draw arbritary squares on a chart.  You can also use the Axis function `toPixels` to convert values to pixels.  I have a function that takes x and y values and draws a square.  If you butted those squares together you could have your regions.

```
var drawSquare = function(x1,x2,y1,y2,color) {
    x1 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(x1);
    x2 = chart.xAxis[0].toPixels(x2);
    y1 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(y1);
    y2 = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(y2);

    var width = x2 - x1;
    var height = y1 - y2;  

    chart.renderer.rect(x1,y2,width, height, 0)
        .attr({
            fill: color,
            zIndex: 0
        })
        .add();
};

drawSquare(0,40,0,35,'rgba(129,184,222,.5)');
drawSquare(40,100,0,35,'rgba(255,223,134,.5)');
drawSquare(0,40,35,150,'rgba(130,215,169,.5)');
drawSquare(40,100,35,150,'rgba(183,153,206,.5)');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lh74L8vu/1/

Comment: Please find here my code: http://pastebin.com/mhtXsDAU what I want is to replace "this" by chart. So how can I use your code to do this.

Comment: @n.Ken What is the problem here? Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle?

Comment: If you want to draw outside the chart area (over the axis), you'll need to create another function that doesn't convert the axis coordinates to pixels.  But, to use the function with this, see http://jsfiddle.net/Lh74L8vu/3/

Comment: @BarbaraLaird there is a problem with toPixel; it always returns a value that's outside of the chart. Is there an alternative for toPixel to know the exact coordinate for a xAxis point ?

Comment: @BarbaraLaird this is my jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/getsuganoir/c57L3cj2/ I want to give to my method xAxis and yAxis values instead of giving pixel values like drawSquare(139.42857142857144, 216.73333333333335, 28.97142857142856, 11.039999999999992, 'rgba(130,215,169,.4)');

Comment: @BarbaraLaird I don't want to work with pixel because if I use it my chart will be changed from a screen to another

Comment: why do you say toPixel doesn't work?  It works fine in my fiddle.